# Inline divs where first div width is responsive and second is fixed

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve the below layout in CSS? It's very simple but its turning out quite complex to code. The red div will contain an image advertisement and will always be 350px wide and always sit on the right side of the page. The green div will contain the website content and its width is dynamic, is should fill the remaining width leftover after the red div is inserted. Both divs should have the same height.

[image]

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.green-div {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;

}

.red-div {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="green-div">
  <p>Green Div</p>
</div>

<div class="red-div">
  <p>Red Div</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox to achieve this.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.green-div {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;

}

.red-div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="green-div">
  <p>Green Div</p>
</div>

<div class="red-div">
  <p>Red Div</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks :) Do you think its got good browser coverage if it uses flex? Will most browsers support this css?

Comment: It seems to have pretty good browser support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox